# Why does one circle go undetected by HoughCircles? How does minDist work?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, hough-transform

I was trying to detect circles in the following image using [HoughCircles](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dd/d1a/group__imgproc__feature.html#ga47849c3be0d0406ad3ca45db65a25d2d).

[image]

Here is the code that I was tuning to find all the circles.

```
    import cv2
    import numpy as np


    img = cv2.imread("images/coins.jpg", 0)

    cimg = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

    minDist = 247

    circles = cv2.HoughCircles(img,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,minDist,
                                param1=170,param2=80,minRadius=0,maxRadius=0)


    print(circles)

    #print("Number of circles detected ", circles.length)


    circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))

    for i in circles[0,:]:
        # draw the outer circle
        cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),2)
        # draw the center of the circle
        cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,0,255),3)


    cv2.imshow('detected circles',cimg)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

For everything I tried, I was not able to detect one coin. The detected circles looked as follows.

[image]

I have three questions here:

- What could be the reason that the second coin from the left in the first row was not detected?
- What does the `minDist` parameter do? Could you explain how it works? I read the documentation but could not understand.
- What do `minRadius` and `maxRadius` of `zero` mean here?

Comment: _**minDist** Minimum distance between the centers of the detected circles. If the parameter is too small, multiple neighbor circles may be falsely detected in addition to a true one. If it is too large, some circles may be missed._  If the distance between your red dots is too small you get false results ...

Comment: _**minRadius** Minimum circle radius.
**maxRadius** Maximum circle radius._  .. The minimal needed radius of your green cirles and the maximum possible radius for the green things ....

Comment: @PatrickArtner Yeah, I had read this in the documentation. But could not understand the multiple circles' thing.

Comment: @PatrickArtner What does maxRadius = 0 mean? The detected circles do not have zero radius.

Comment: See the 2005 -- 00 are circles ... if you lower the 247 to say 40, guess they will be detected as well. and the **0** is the defaultvalue given ... I would _guess_ that means is is _not_ used (although the documentation does not say so explicitly). But if it _would_ be used when 0 ... it should never find anything, should it?

Comment: I would probably write a loop and count the length of `circles` start with a minDist of 300 and decrease it by 10 every time you get less then 8 results from applying `HoughCircles`. If you have an idea about the size of the coins in pixles I would set minRadius to 2/3 of a coin-radius and maxRadius to 4/3 of a coin-radius to rule out finding very small or too big circles. If you still do not get 8 coins, you probably need to enhance the contour (sharpen f.e) but I would guess the image is fine as is as the differences between the 7 and the 1 coin aren't that great to a naked eye.

Comment: “For everything I tried, I was not able to detect one coin.” It would be helpful if you showed *what* you tried. It makes answering easier.

Answer (score 4):

1. What could be the reason that the second coin from the left in the first row was not detected?

   - The second coin is not detected because of the canny edge detection parameter: `param1`.
     Reduce the value of `param1` and you will get a perfect answer.
2. What does the `minDist` parameter do? Could you explain how it works? I read the documentation but could not understand.

   - And as per the documentation `minDist` is the minimum value between 2 circles. If you reduce the value of `minDist` you will get multiple neighbor circles.
3. What do `minRadius` and `maxRadius` of `zero` mean here?

   - `minRadius` Minimum circle radius.
   - `maxRadius` Maximum circle radius. If `<= 0`, uses the **maximum image dimension**.  If `< 0`, returns centers without finding the radius.

Here is full code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


img = cv2.imread("coins.jpg", 0)

cimg = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

minDist = 247

circles = cv2.HoughCircles(img,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,minDist,
                param1=150,param2=80,minRadius=0,maxRadius=0)


print(circles)

#print("Number of circles detected ", circles.length)


circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))

for i in circles[0,:]:
    # draw the outer circle
    cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),2)
    # draw the center of the circle
    cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,0,255),3)

##cv2.imwrite('detected_circle.jpg',cimg)
cv2.imshow('detected circles',cimg)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Here you can see I got the second coin too.
[image]